# Android Database operation in Asynctask blocks UI Thread

Tags: database, android-asynctask, blocking, ui-thread

I'm performing a Database operation in the `doInBackground` method inside an `AsyncTask` on `Android`.

For some reason, the `UI` get blocked during the 5-6 seconds that the operation takes.

It does not make any sense for me, the operacion inside the `doInBackground` should not be executed in the `UI Thread`, right?

Here is my code:

```
private class CountItems extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.asynTask_loading));
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // This operation takes 5-6 seconds.
        return app.databaseSession().getMyObjectDao().count(selectedProject, filter, null, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        counterTextView.setText(String.valueOf(result));

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I've made a test. If I put a `Thread.sleep()` inside the `doInBackground` method, it is executed in a different `Thread` without blocking the `UI`.

Like this:

```
 @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same problem... seems that SQLITE Insert block the ui thread